# Blurring live camera preview with OpenGL 2.0 on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have properly set up the Camera preview using SurfaceTexture and OpenGL.
After days of research with trial and error, I'm unable to blur the pixels, there seems to be very little documentation on this.

The desired effect is blurring and dimming the camera while opening DrawerLayout.
So far all the apps and guides that I've found blur a bitmap.

Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a `fragment shader` and apply your blurring filter over there. So for your use case you will have to keep one flag inside shader which determines whether blur has to be applied or not. Say when your drawer is about to open or starting to close you can set and unset that flag.

a [simple google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fragment%20shader%20blurring) will point you to many further readings on this topic.